# What pedals should I upgrade to for racing on the road and possibly track?

Tags: product-rec, pedals, racing, clipless

I currently have SPD pedals on all of my bikes. I've stuck with them so far as they worked relatively well and I couldn't justify having two types of shoes.

I can justify two types of shoes now.

These pedals/shoes/etc would be for my road bike and likely used on the track as I am going to spend a bit of time at the local velodrome this winter. My primary criteria is probably strength, with price second. I'm a sprinter and saving money is always good. Weight doesn't really matter at this point.

The Look and Shimano road pedals look good, but they have a number of different models across the board. Any suggestions or ones to stay away from?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the Look Keo Classic pedals if you are not hyper-sensitive to the weight.  They offer a carbon version if you decide to spend the extra bucks for the lighter version.  Popular and well-liked pedal with the extremely common Look cleat style.

I picked my pair up from probikekit.com, they had the best price at the time and offered free shipping but YMMV.

Comment: +1 for Look for me, but most of my mates ride SPD-SL. Shimano seem significantly heavier, but the cleats do seem to last longer.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be fairly subjective. I ride with Time MTB pedals and keep up with anyone in my category. Stick with known brands and I'm sure you'll be fine. Time, Look, SpeedPlay, Shimano, Crank Brothers...

Answer (score 1):

On the track you want a pedal with little float, on a road bike you'll want a bit more, but they will both still be a lot stiffer than your current SPDs. I presume you'll be using your own pedals on the track bikes so it isn't a question of needing to liaise with the track to confirm to their standard.

I use Look Keo on the road bike mainly because there's a decent selection of pedals available so the upgrade path just isn't something to think about.

Some decent [background reading](http://www.bikeradar.com/fitness/article/buyers-guide-to-clipless-road-pedals--15).

Answer (score 1):

I ride Speedplays and will never ride anything else. Due to the amount of float it's unnecessary to have an intensive cleat fit for these. So basically you can spend $50 less for Looks or Times, but then you have to spend that on a cleat fitting, if you want them adjusted correctly.

That being said, some people don't enjoy the amount of float. Newer Speedplays have adjustable float, though. I would definitely try a pair before making a decision. I love them.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think I've ever had a problem lining cleats up on my own. I just align them with the marks on the shoes, and adjust slightly if that doesn't feel right after a few rides.

Comment: The spindles should be aligned with your metatarsal; I've never seen a marking on a cleat for this as it's relative to each foot. It's a question of how much you're going to be riding. If you're putting in a lot of miles at high intensity it's absolutely worth getting a cleat fit. If you're riding once or twice a week at moderate intensity, go for it. If nothing hurts, it works. If you have pain, it's worth considering a cleat fit.